# Show that $nu_n$ converges to $1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\Bbb{K}=\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$

> Let $(u_n)\in\Bbb{K}^{\Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $(n(u_n+u_{2n}))_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ converges to $\frac{3}{2}$ and $u_n\rightarrow 0$.
>
> It is asking to prove that  $(nu_n)$ converges  to $1$.

If I denote $v_n=nu_n$, we have $v_n+\frac{v_{2n}}{2}\rightarrow 3/2$.
If $V_n$ is positive then I can conclude that $v_n$ is bounded and use some result I have in my course.

Any Ideas How can I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $v_n=nu_n$, and $\displaystyle v_n+\frac{v_{2n}}{2}=3/2+a_n$, with $a_n\to 0$ if $n\to +\infty$.

We have hence $\displaystyle v_n=-\frac{v_{2n}}{2}+3/2+a_n$. Replace $n$ by $2n$, and use the expression for $v_{2n}$,  we get
$$v_n=(-\frac{1}{2})^2v_{2^2n}+\frac{3}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})+a_n+(-\frac{1}{2})a_{2n}$$

By induction on $k$, we have for all $n$:
$$v_n=(-\frac{1}{2})^k v_{2^k n}+\frac{3}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+(-\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}))+a_n+(-\frac{1}{2})a_{2n}+\cdots+(-\frac{1}{2})^{k-1})a_{2^{k-1}n}$$
Now  fix $n$, and let $k\to +\infty$, ; as $u_m\to 0$ as $m\to+\infty$, we get that $\displaystyle (-\frac{1}{2})^k v_{2^k n}\to 0$, and
$$v_n=1+\sum_{j\geq 0}(-1)^{j}\frac{a_{2^jn}}{2^j}$$

As $a_n\to 0$ if $n\to +\infty$, it is now easy to see that $\displaystyle \sum_{j\geq 0}(-1)^{j}\frac{a_{2^jn}}{2^j} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, and we are done.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand why $\displaystyle (-\frac{1}{2})^k v_{2^k n}\to 0$?

Comment: We have $\displaystyle (-\frac{1}{2})^k v_{2^k n}=(-1)^k nu_{2^kn}$. Recall that $n$ is fixed; as $k\to +\infty$, $m=2^kn\to +\infty$, and so $u_m\to 0$.

Comment: Right, I was a bit confused with $m$,$n$ and $k$. Thank you, It's nice trick to introduce $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $v=\lim v_n$ (of course when $n$ go to $+\infty$). Now you since $v_{2n}$ is a subsecuence of $v_n$ you can conclude $v=\lim v_n=\lim v_{2n}$

You now $\lim v_n+\frac{v_{2n}}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$, but you also know:
$$\lim v_n+\frac{v_{2n}}{2}=\lim v_n+\lim \frac{v_{2n}}{2}=\lim v_n+ \frac{\lim v_{2n}}{2}=v+\frac{v}{2}=\frac{3}{2}v$$

Then

$$\frac{3}{2}v=\frac{3}{2}$$
And then
$$v=1$$

And you conclude $\lim v_n=\lim nu_n=v=1$.

Comment: How do you know that (lim v_n) exist?

Comment: for any sucesion $a_n$ and constant $c\not =0$, the limit $ca_n$ converges if and only if $a_n$ converges, in this case take $a_n=n u_n$ and $c=3/2$